# How I can add TASKS, ISSUES and BUGS to a Sprint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sprint

I am new to Azure DevOps (previously used JIRA) and I don't understand how I can add Tasks, issues and bugs to a Sprint.

The Process I chose is `Agile`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But honestly, this isn't really a question about programming. I think you should rather study the documentation for that tooling. This sounds like a very basic activity, that is for sure documented.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AzureDevOps

1. You need to create and define a [sprint in AzureDevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/define-sprints?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)
2. Once after you defined the sprint,you add the [Task/bugs to the corresponding sprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/add-tasks?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#add-tasks-to-backlog-items-1)

[image]

You can also move the Task/Bug to any sprint like below

[image]

Happy Learning!